# KubernetesPodOperator - run entire command pulled from XCOM

Tags: python, kubernetes, airflow

I am working on Airflow 1.10.

I have problem with running commands on KubernetesPodOperator, where entire command is evaluated during DAG runtime.

I am generating command in DAG runtime as some of command's arguments depends on parameters passed by user.

As I read from documentation
KubernetesPodOperator expects list of strings or list of jinja templates:

```
    :param arguments: arguments of the entrypoint. (templated)
        The docker image's CMD is used if this is not provided.
```

I have PythonOperator which generates command and push it to XCOM and KubernetesPodOperator
where in arguments I pass command generated by PythonOperator.

```
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.contrib.operators.kubernetes_pod_operator import KubernetesPodOperator


def command_maker():
    import random # random is to illustrate that we don't know arguments value before runtime
    return f"my_command {random.randint(1, 10)} --option {random.randint(1, 4)}"

def create_tasks(dag):
    first = PythonOperator(
        task_id="generate_command",
        python_callable=command_maker,
        provide_context=True,
        dag=dag,
    )
    second = KubernetesPodOperator(
        namespace='some_namespace',
        image='some_image',
        name='execute_command',
        dag=dag,
        arguments=[f'{{ ti.xcom_pull(dag_id="{dag.dag_id}", task_ids="generate_command", key="return_value")}}']
    )
    second.set_upstream(first)
```

Unfortunately KubernetesPodOperator doesn't run this command correctly as he tries to run something like this:

```
[my_command 4 --option 2]
```

Is there way to eval this list at KubernetesPodOperator runtime
or am I enforced to push all runtime arguments into separate XCOM's?
I would like to avoid such solution as it required lot of changes in my project.

```
         arguments=[
            "my_command",
            f'{{ ti.xcom_pull(dag_id="{dag.dag_id}", task_ids="generate_command", key="first_argument")}}',
            "--option",
            f'{{ ti.xcom_pull(dag_id="{dag.dag_id}", task_ids="generate_command", key="second_argument")}}',
         ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have working solution for Airflow 1.10 I had to use BaseOperator.pre_execute hook.

```
from airflow.contrib.operators.kubernetes_pod_operator import KubernetesPodOperator
from airflow.lineage import prepare_lineage

class UnpackCommandKubernetesPodOperator(KubernetesPodOperator):
    @prepare_lineage
    def pre_execute(self, context):
        self.arguments = self.arguments[0].split(" ")
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that JINJA template returns the template as string by default.

In recent Airflow, however (As of Airlfow 2.1.0)  you can render the templates as native python objects:

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/operators.html#rendering-fields-as-native-python-objects

By using a `render_template_as_native_obj=True` parameter when you create DAG.

Then you need to format your output in the way that python's `literal_eval` will be able to convert it to python object. In your case you have to make the output similar to:

`[ 'my_command', '4', '--option', '2' ]`

Note that this parameter will return native objects for all your templates so if they return some values that [literal_eval understands](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/nativetypes/) - they will also be converted to native types (and you might have some unintended side-effects.

Comment: Is there any workaround to achieve this in Airflow 1.10?